# Dynamically load js files in "use strict"; mode

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Working on a Single Page Architecture project, there are a lot of `*.js` files lazy loaded to DOM.

The file getting included may not have the line `"use strict";` but the solution should force `"use strict";` for all js files included after loading the initial scripts (Application library files).

Comment: The easiest thing would be to ensure that all the files have `use strict` and use something like jshint to enforce this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use ajax to get the scripts text and append the `"use strict";` to the scripts and `eval()` it or append it to body as `<script>` tag. Example using jQuery:

```
$.get('foo.js', function(script) {
  $('<script type="text/javascript">').html('"use strict";\r\n' + script).appendTo('body');
  // OR
  eval('"use strict";\r\n' + script);
});
```